# Javascript function callbacks

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I was going through the following piece of code and couldn't understand what was happening behind the scenes when each method is invoked. How do both the methods interact with each other ?

```
var employeeDb = require('../database/employees');
exports.getEmployees = getEmployees;
exports.getEmployee = getEmployee;

function getEmployees(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(null, employeeDb);
    }, 500);
}

function getEmployee(employeeId, callback) {
    getEmployees(function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        var result = data.find(function(item) {
            return item.id === employeeId;
        });
        callback(null, result);
    });
}
```

Can anyone please explain in detail ?

Comment: It would help a lot if *you* would explain in detail what the problem is. What parts do you understand and not understand?

Comment: And in the code you posted, *nothing happens* because neither of those two functions are invoked.

Comment: This is a sample code in a Node.js application. Exports is a module to which two methods are attached and exposed in a file _employees.js_. I am not able to understand how the _callback_ function gets called.

Secondly, _getEmployee_ is able to access _getEmployees_ ?

Comment: why was my question downvoted? I think it's a genuine question.

Comment: Is the code inside the _getEmployee_'s _getEmployees_  method the _callback_ method body ? This is the confusing part.

Comment: Yes, inside `getEmployee()` there is a call to `getEmployees()`, and an anonymous function is passed as an argument. That anonymous function is the `callback` argument to `getEmployees()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var employeeDb = require('../database/employees');
```

Whatever is exported from `../database/employees` is now assigned to `employeeDb`.

---

```
exports.getEmployees = getEmployees;
exports.getEmployee = getEmployee;
```

We are choosing to export our `getEmployees` and `getEmployee` methods from below to whatever file `require`s the file we are currently working on. These two methods already exist in the JavaScript engine's eyes due to *function hoisting*.

---

```
function getEmployees(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(null, employeeDb);
    }, 500);
}
```

Whatever callback function is passed into `getEmployees` WILL be executed.... after at least 500ms have passed. That function must be expecting `null` and the `employeeDb` (from the `require` statement from the very first line).

If this is Node.js code, it's common to pass in `null` into a callback to indicate "we ran into no errors!".

---

```
function getEmployee(employeeId, callback) {
    getEmployees(function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        var result = data.find(function(item) {
            return item.id === employeeId;
        });
        callback(null, result);
    });
}
```

This function accepts an `employeeId` and `callback` function. The function says, 'hey `getEmployees()`, please run right now, but when you are done, execute this anonymous function I'm giving to you as your only argument.' `getEmployees()` sets a 500ms timer, and once 500ms expires, it decides to run our anonymous function by giving it `null` and `employeeDb`.

Our anonymous function accepts `null` as `var error` (from the parameters) and `employeeDb` as `var data` (from the parameters). Since `null` was given to us, the `if(error){}` conditional fails, allowing us to move onto the `var result...` line of code.

That `var result...` line of code says: "hey `data`, please run your `find` method, and do whatever you're supposed to do with the anonymous function.. whether it be running it when you're done (aka async), or whether it be running it multiple times synchronously (like a `forEach` loop)."

If `data.find()` is an asynchronous operation, then your `callback(null, result` is in the wrong spot.

If `data.find()` is a synchronous operation, then whatever callback was originally passed in as a parameter will be executed as: "hey, we got no error, so lemme give you `null` instead so you know that... and oh also here's the `result` I got, bye!"

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be a kind of simulation code which simulates some server-side APIs (**getEmployees** and **getEmployee**) that give access to the database. Let me give a very brief logical explanation of these two API functions:

### getEmployees(callback)

This function uses **setTimeout** function to simulate the delay in server-side communication. When this function is called, the parameter *callback* is called after 500 milliseconds with two parameters; the *error* and *employee database(employeeDb)* objects.

### getEmployee(employeeId, callback)

This function is called to find an employee with given id (*employeeId*) with a callback mechanism. The API uses the previous server side access API and passes the callback to it. Whenever the server returns data through callback then it calls the find method of the database object pushed by getEmployee API. When the employee with the given id is found then the result is returned back through the callback mechanism. In this code, it is assumed to be no error is generated during the *find* operation.